# Wordpress - show a container div when page has child

Tags: wordpress

I have a parent page which I want to list the child pages of. I have the code working for it. But I also want to only show a container div for these child page listings if the page has children.

So show container div if child pages exist, list child pages in the container div. If no child pages exist, don't show container div.

Code so far:

```
<?php
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *    FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID."    AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY post_title", 'OBJECT');    ?>
<?php if ( $child_pages ) : foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) : setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
<div class="child-thumb">
    <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>">
  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'medium'); ?>
 <h4 class="arrow_box green" ><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?></h4></a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; endif;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You should break-up the if statement. Just make it a simple check for 'child_pages' and if it passes render a container div, then comes the foreach loop. On a side note, there are plenty of official WP commands for grabbing posts properly, is there a reason you're querying the database directly?

Comment: No reason at all! other then, its what I inherited and don't know any different. If you have a better way to do it I'll gladly be educated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to split up the if statement so you can do something before the foreach loop runs. Something like this should get you started. FYI there may be a better way to grab the child posts and do the check for child_pages.

```
<?php
$child_pages = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' =>'page',
    'posts_per_page' =>-1,
    'post_parent' => $post_id,
    'order_by' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC' ) );

if ($child_pages) {
?>

    <div id="child_pages">

        <?php foreach ($child_pages as $pageChild) : setup_postdata( $pageChild); ?>
            <div class="child-thumb">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID, 'medium'); ?>
                <h4 class="arrow_box green"><?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?></h4></a>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>

<?php end if;?>
```